# sampling distribution of a test statistic when doing permutation test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, permutation, sampling-distribution

In a permutation test, we have a test statistic $T$ (for example t-test, f-test, etc.) that is applied to the original data to obtain an observed value $o_{obs}$ for the test statistic. Next, the data is permuted and we use $T$ on this permuted dataset to calculate some observed value $o_{perm}$. This permutation process is repeated many times and the p-value of $T$ becomes the percentage of times that $o_{obs} < o_{perm}$.

Given that the p-value is estimated in this way, I don't see any reason why we would need to know the sampling distribution of $T$, given that the p-value is calculated without using such sampling distribution.

On the other hand, this seems to me to be very weird, since this means that many possible tests $T$ could in principle be used.

So this makes me wonder: do we need to know the sampling distribution of $T$, if we are using it for a permutation test? If so, why?

Comment: Connecting what you are doing--recomputing $T$ for permutations of the data--to a p-value requires a *strong assumption* about the data distribution; namely, *exchangeability.*  Under this assumption you are directly estimating the sampling distribution of $T$ when you do the permutation test.  In light of this, in what sense do you intend us to understand the phrase "need to know"?

Comment: @whuber what I mean is that for "usual" statistics (like t-test, f-test,...) the sampling distribution is well known. Now suppose I decided to use a weird test statistic, something like the cube of the t-test formula. This statistic would be useless as nobody (I assume) ever calculated the sampling distribution of this t-test cubed. So i wouldn't be able to derive a p-value. Except that with the permutation procedure I am able to indeed estimate this distribution. This confuses me as it seems that the permutation procedure allows for many statistical tests to sprung up out of thin air

Comment: The sampling distribution of a t-test or an F-test is only "well known" in general when the population distribution is **normal**; outside that in some special cases you can work it out but otherwise ... you don't know what it is. The permutation distribution only assumes exchangeability under the null, rather than an explicit distributional form, so it's a vastly weaker requirement to get a test with 'exact' significance levels (it will 'work' significance-level-wise for essentially any distribution); it should also have asymptotic relative efficiency of 1 at the normal.